# calling ruby methods with arguments inside ERB?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am storing a response in javascript variable. This is inside a .html.erb file.

```
var file = response.data.files[0];
```

I first made a call using

```
var f = "<%=link_onedrive%>"
```

This successfully calls a method link_onedrive

Then I made this call

```
var f = "<%=link_onedrive(%>file<%=)%>"
```

It throws an error

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

My question is how to make a ruby method call with argument from a erb.

**edited**

here's my link_onedrive

```
def link_onedrive(file)
 uri = URI.parse("https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0")
 http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
 http.use_ssl = true
 req = Net::HTTP::Post.new("https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/file.link/action.createLink)
 req.content_type = "application/json"   
 req.body = '{"type" : "view"}'
 response = http.request(req)
 arr = JSON.parse(response.body)
 arr["link"]["webUrl"]
end
```

Comment: ok... first you need to realise that ruby parses the erb and runs all the ruby *first* and generates some html+js code... that then gets sent to the browser and the browser runs the js that has already been created at this point. You can't call the ruby from the javascript, because by that stage, there is no ruby left... just javascript

Comment: But, in that case my first call is success. the method link_onedrive is inside the application helper and it's getting called the first time. My argument passing during the second time is the problem

Comment: yes... but it's literally not possible to do what you're trying to do above... because by the time you have the javascript 'file' variable - it's too late to run any ruby. If there's a way you can get the file during the ruby-parsing part (rather than the javascript-running part), then you can pass it to the ruby.

Comment: perhaps it would help us to help you if you showed us what `link_onedrive` actually does

Comment: link_overdrive is supposed to call a API POST request with that file as one of it's parameters.

Comment: Don't tell me, show me... with actual code (edit your question and put it there, because code-formatting in comments is really crap). :)

Comment: Taryn East i have edited it is this information enough for you

Comment: Ok - looks like this could easily be converted to a new controller action that returns the required url, and then your javascript can just use AJAX to post the filename to that action and get the url back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok... first you need to realise how erb works.

At the end of a controller action: Rails parses the erb and runs all the ruby first and uses it to generate some html+js code... at this point, the bit that says `<%= link_onedrive %>` gets completely overwritten by the result of calling the `link_onedrive` method... it's not there in the html anymore.

This html+js then gets sent to the browser and the browser (on the client's machine) runs the js that has already been created at this point.

You can't call the ruby from the javascript, because by that stage, there is no ruby left... just javascript.

If you want to call ruby methods from your javascript - you probably need to set up an ajax-post that posts to a controller that runs the ruby, and then returns a result that the javascript does something with.

or we need to help you rewrite the two bits of code... to get what you actually want some other way (but to do that we probably need to see what `link_onedrive` actually does)

Comment: This means all the ruby methods with a constant values can be called but we can't process a dynamic value with a ruby function. right!

Comment: You can, you just need to actually have the variable in the ruby, instead of the javascript ;) or post to the ruby from the javascript after you get the value.

Comment: how can I assign response.data.files[0]; to a ruby variable.

Comment: i don't know what is `response.datas.files[0]` and how does it get set? is the same information available in the ruby `params` hash?

Comment: This is a response coming as a success from a javascript method

Comment: Yes I am aware of that... but where does the javascript get the info from? is it a field in a form that gets posted? or is it from somwhere else?

Comment: It's Microsoft's onedrive where they personally have a javascript which opens file picker upon selection of a file it's giving this response as a file object

Comment: Now... you need to try the AJAX thing - you can google for that if you've not done it before. Doing it is beyond the scope of this question... So... have a go at it yourself... then if you get stuck, come back to Stack Overflow and ask a *new* question (we need to close this one up now as it's done)